# Why cant I use a loaded movieclip at the same time on two locations?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, loader, movieclip

I'm loading a swf, place it in a array and then use it in various locations.

Everything works as it should, but when I add the movieclip in two different places at the same time (in completely different classes), its only displayed on one location.

I don't get a error, it just only shows it once.

This is how I load the swf and add it to my array:

```
img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
url = new URLRequest("my_file.swf");
img.load(url);

function loaded(event:Event):void{
    var mc:MovieClip = event.target.content as MovieClip;
    testArr.push(mc);
}
```

And this is how I display the movieclip:

```
var displayMc:MovieClip = MovieClip(myClass.testArr[0]);
addChild(displayMc);

var otheryMc:MovieClip = MovieClip(myClass.testArr[0]);
addChild(otheryMc);
```

Should I duplicate the movieclip in the array to be able to display it on two locations or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't display one MovieClip in two different places. Yes, you should duplicate the MovieClip. Try this code:

```
var duplicatedImg:Loader = new Loader();
duplicatedImg.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
duplicatedImg.loadBytes(img.contentLoaderInfo.bytes);
```